# Spring Mongodb aggregate pipeline group by time interval

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, kotlin

```
@Document
data class Entity(
    @Id
    val id: UUID,
    val takenAt: LocalDateTime,
)
```

I need to get result grouped by 15 minutes interval from that collection. Query works as i excepted:

```
db.getCollection("entity").aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": ["$takenAt", ISODate("1970-01-01")] },
                    { "$mod": [{ "$subtract": ["$takenAt", ISODate("1970-01-01")] }, 1000 * 60 * 15] }
                ]
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(1656681300000), 
    "count" : 9.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(1656683100000), 
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

I would like write that same code in spring, but i get error: `org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readEndDocument can only be called when ContextType is DOCUMENT or SCOPE_DOCUMENT, not when ContextType is ARRAY.`

```
    @Aggregation(
        pipeline = [
            "{'\$group':{ " +
                    "'_id': { '\$subtract': [{ '\$subtract': ['\$takenAt', ISODate('1970-01-01')]}," +
                    "{ '\$mod': [{ '\$subtract': ['\$takenAt', ISODate('1970-01-01')] }, 1000*60*15] }" +
                    "]" +
                    "}, " +
                    "'count': { '\$sum' : 1 }" +
                    "}}"
        ]
    )
```

I dont know where is the problem

Comment: You don't need the backslash ('\') escaping before the `$` sign for the operators and the variables - e.g.,  `'\$group'` is written as `'$group'` only.

Comment: I use kotlin in this case and the backslash is required